# How do I know a mac needs to restart?

Tags: automation, restart, reboot, monitoring

Is there a way to figure out from a script whether a Mac needs to reboot? A file, the presence or contents of which I could monitor perhaps?

I'm looking for an equivalent to the file `/var/run/reboot-required` found on my Ubuntu boxes. My use case would be to centrally monitor my servers (and perhaps laptops) using Puppet, `collectd` or… well, something.

Answer (score 6):

Like Linux, OS X is designed not to **require** restarting. There is no system wide means to determine if a restart is required - or even requested by a process.

For situations where a restart is required, the process responsible for needing the restart is also responsible for organising the restart.

Tools that update OS X are most likely to request a restart.

### softwareupdate

Take a look at the  [`softwareupdate` manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/softwareupdate.8.html) for the most likely candidate to request a restart.

`softwareupdate` prints a message at the end of the updating process stating if a restart is required. The calling script or user is then responsible for restarting.

### Delayed Updates

If an update requires a restart to be successfully and safely installed, OS X will delay the updating process. The update will wait until the next restart or shut down.

This approach allows updates to be downloaded as part of a schedule but not interrupt or interfere with running processes or active users.

### Pending Updates

To see if an update is pending, check the contents of `/Library/Updates/`. This folder appears to contain property list files documenting packages and updates queued for installation.

You can use the tool `defaults` in your scripts to read `plist` files such as `/Library/Updates/index.plist`:

```
defaults read /Library/Updates/index.plist InstallAtLogout
```

Comment: Agreed. Yet, some system updates say awful, un-unixy things like _You have installed one or more updates that requires that you restart your computer. Please restart immediately._ And it's these i'd like to catch, remotely.

Comment: Take a look inside the `/Library/Updates/` folder. I suspect this is where pending updates are documented.

Comment: I will. Sorry for my previous quick comment. Only the first paragraph of your answer had come through at that time. I can't though find any indication of `softwareupdate` being able to tell me i'll need to reboot a mac.

Oddly, the manual page omits a rather nifty command to set the URL of a software catalog, to force using a local repo instead of the one on Apple's servers.

Comment: When used to begin a command line update  `softwareupdate` will output a restart required message. Otherwise the tool lists available updates. Hopefully the `/Library/Updates` folder will provide the information you need.

Comment: @danielAzuelos nothing religious about it. the answerer simply said os x was *designed* not to require restarts. he didn't say it *doesn't* require restarts in practice. this answer indeed explains why os x has no mechanism to determine if the system requires a restart—it was *designed* to never need to.

Comment: How would you plan a firmware or a kernel extension update without a restart? How would you manage an OS life cycle without updates?

Comment: @danielAzuelos A lot of these things are actually possible, but the discussion of how to accomplish it is probably beyond the scope of this site :-)

Comment: I've now received an update which requires rebooting. The /Library/Updates/index.plist has a key `InstallAtLogout` (which i never do because this is a server) and an `InstallLater`. Only `softwareupdate -l` will return a row including the string `[restart]` and of course softwareupdate is less than an immediate process.